# iOS fetch Safari Saved Credit Card information in 3rd party apps

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

I have been poking around safari saved passwords recently and I went through the WWDC session that talks in detail about accessing saved credentials from safari and adding saved credentials.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-506/

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/506xxeo80e5kykp/506/506_ensuring_continuity_between_your_app_and_web_site.pdf

I also read this and found this is the code to get the saved credentials out of Safari,

```
SecRequestSharedWebCredential(NULL, NULL, ^(CFArrayRef credentials, CFErrorRef error) {

    if (error != NULL) {
        // If an error occurs, handle the error here.
        [self handleError:error];
        return;
    }

    BOOL success = NO;
    CFStringRef server = NULL;
    CFStringRef userName = NULL;
    CFStringRef password = NULL;

    // If credentials are found, use them.
    if (CFArrayGetCount(credentials) > 0) {

        // There will only ever be one credential dictionary
        CFDictionaryRef credentialDict =
        CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(credentials, 0);

        server = CFDictionaryGetValue(credentialDict, kSecAttrServer);
        userName = CFDictionaryGetValue(credentialDict, kSecAttrAccount);
        password = CFDictionaryGetValue(credentialDict, kSecSharedPassword);

    }

});
```

It is pretty much evident that we can access shared credentials from safari, I have seen apps do these things and I also saw this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90978/secure-passwords-with-safari-autofill-ios-8) that details the steps to do the integration.

All is well until this point, now I also see you can save credit card information in safari and it automatically helps the user to pre-fill credit card information on payment sites.

[image]

[image]

Now comes the question, can third party apps fetch the saved credit card information that is saved in safari and vice versa? I have done so many google searches and it is point black, no exact matches on how to do so programatically. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Facing same issue. http://9to5mac.com/2014/10/11/ios-8-how-to-use-camera-to-enter-in-credit-card-info/ I want to implement something like this in my App.

Comment: @Abhi Sorry no such apis available now, even in iOS 10.

Comment: Any update with latest iOS versions.. iOS 12 has the autofill framework to store the passwords but not the cards..

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your app has a companion website/backend, one option is to use the Safari View Controller ([SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)) to launch an 'add credit card' page on your website - Safari view controller has access to saved credit card info (as well as other autofill info). Once the user has entered their new credit card, you can return back to your app's main flow.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some example of this technique?

Comment: @actuosus Not really. It's a pretty straightforward technique. Which part are you struggling to understand/implement?